# MAX + 1 Primary key in parallel transactions

Tags: t-sql

1st) I know about identity and autoincremment and i support that 101%, but sometimes, you have no choise (like legacy system/politics)

Hello let's assume i have an insert statement like this:

```
insert into SomeTable
select (select coallesce(max(ID),0)+1 from SomeTable),
       @ParameterValue
```

Now i have two applications that take a cmd line parameter and do this:

```
//    Begin Transaction with isolation level ReadUncommited
for(i=0; i<100000; i++)
    // Run the insert statement with the cmd line parameters
//    Commit Transaction
```

Now, i would expect (want) to see after doing select * from SomeTable that the applications take turns entering the data (s for instance if one application has cmd line value = 'A' and the other 'B' I would get something like:

```
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   B
5   A
6   B  (..., i think you get the point)
```

I tried to achive this by:

```
insert into SomeTable with (tablock) - doesnt work, first one app finishes, then the other one

insert into SomeTable with (udplock) - i get PK violation
```

I am slowly getting desperate. So, the question is like, is there some kind of lock, that locks the table only for the duration of the statement, but doesnt hold until end of transaction?

Thank you very much

Oh and just to be sure, empty spaces between id is not a problem

Comment: Just a suggestion but Query hints are... hints not rules and the engine is not obligated to follow it. In fact you can profile to see how the lock is escalating. Also there's concurrence at play here and one transaction ill block another in some way. You can try to isolate the insert inside the loop but that's likely to perform horrible

Answer (score 0):

You could move the transaction to inside the loop and use REPEATABLE READ
But that is going to hurt response time

```
for(i=0; i<100000; i++) 
{
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
    GO
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    GO
    insert into SomeTable  
    select (select coallesce(max(ID),0)+1 from SomeTable), @ParameterValue
    GO
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    GO
}
```

A tablock and have one wait on the other is going to be faster.
There is a lot of overhead to taking a lock.
Take it once at the table level and insert 100000 is efficient.
It is one database and one write head on the other end.
Two programs writing at the same time is not going to make it faster.

Comment: Sorry, that wont work. The transaction has to be on the outside. This is simplified down from the real problem, there are several 'interfaces' (.exe application) running that import and export data to/from DB/File. And i want to get some of the interface (ie. Order interface and Customer interface to run at the same time, but they both can write to the same table with a non-identity primary key) and i dont want one interface to stop at start and then wait for the other interface

Comment: Sorry, that's not possible to let the loop inside a transaction AND two transaction get the "right" values from one another since one need another insert to be commited. Also you ill need to compute (query) the new maxvalue for each insert. The only performatic way to do it is by one loop entirely block another. Can you try to lower the loop iterations to fasten the block time?

Comment: I don't know how you legacy system work and the things you can alter on it but for that multiple executables running scenario its more a "messagery" problem. The ideal solution is to not insert direct in the tables but in a queue and let a singleton like process to handle the task to get from the queue to the target tables. Of course if you immedialty needs to get feedback from that inserts (example: if you need to know the generated Id) it seems to be a problem.

Comment: For a final comment: There's one "hack" can help you. Since you are generating the ids yourself you can avoid PK violations by inserting diferent values. If you got two executables one can insert pair values and the other, odds values. If you got 10 executables each one can insert a Id finished by 0..9 and so on. Not a elegant way to solve it but can work (and generate tons of maintenance headache)

Comment: @jean You know you are commenting on an answer.  It is not my legacy system.   I don't know how it works either.